# mongorestore issue : Cannot restore users with schema version 1 to a system with server version 2.5.4 or greater

Tags: mongodb, migration, mongorestore

I have a mongodb production database running on mongo 2.4.8 and I would like to upgrade to 2.6.x.

The way we want to do that is first load the data to another server running 2.6.3 using `mongorestore`. However when running the `mongorestore`command we get the following error:

```
Cannot restore users with schema version 1 to a system with server version 2.5.4 or greater
```

I cannot find anything related to this issue and do't know what to do. In case it matters, the database itself was not created from scratch with mongo 2.4.x but with previous versions.

What ca I do ? Is there another way of doing this other than using mongorestore ?

Thank you in advance for your help ...

Comment: Do you know what version was used to create the database? Do you know what the steps were to upgrde to 2.4? I recommend reading over the [upgrade and changelog docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/) that can be find in the linked section of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take to upgrade your user schema with the 2.4 `mongodump`.

#### 1) Restore into MongoDB 2.4 and then upgrade to 2.6

This follows the normal [2.6 upgrade path](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/). Instead of trying to `mongorestore` your 2.4 backup directly into 2.6, restore into a 2.4 instance and then upgrade to 2.6.

It is recommended that before upgrading, you run [db.upgradeCheckAllDBs()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.upgradeCheckAllDBs/#db.upgradeCheckAllDBs) via a 2.6 `mongo` shell. This checks for any potential [compatibility issues](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/) due to changes in MongoDB 2.6. For example, 2.6 implements stronger enforcement of index field definitions and key length restrictions.

#### 2) Restore into MongoDB 2.6 using 2.4 `mongorestore` and then upgrade the user schema

This approach requires the MongoDB 2.4 version of  `mongorestore`

- start up your MongoDB 2.6 `mongod` *without* auth enabled
- `mongorestore` your backup using a 2.4 version of `mongorestore`
- run the [`authSchemaUpgrade` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade-authorization/#upgrade-authorization-schema) in your 2.6 `mongo` shell:

  ```
  db.adminCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1 });
  ```
- restart your 2.6 `mongod` with auth enabled

Answer (score 1):

Three approaches that I can think of:

1. First, if you are running as a replica set, I'd upgrade the members
   one by one. If you're not running as a replica set that's bad,
   MongoDB is really not designed for production usage with a single
   instance. Details on converting to a replica set and in a rolling
   upgrade here:
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/ and here:
   http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/#
2. Second, if you are running on a file system that supports snapshots
   (like Amazon EBS or Linux LVM) you can snapshot the database files,
   restore to a new file system and start up a new mongod process using
   2.6. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/
3. Third, try exporting the data via mongoexport and loading it via
   mongoimport. It's not the same as mongodump/mongorestore so it has
   some limitations (it's not a full backup of the database, just a
   text dump of the collections) but might help you get past this issue
   with mongorestore: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/import-export/

Comment: Hi,thank you for your answer. I am already using a replica set. I know that upgrading members 1 by 1 works magically. My issue here is the data itself. I don't want to discover issues when it is too late. This is the reason why I want to reload the data somewhere else. I know how to export the data and already have an mongodump archive.

Comment: FYI: `mongoexport` isn't a recommendable option for database backup/restore as it will not reliably capture type information, does not include index definitions, and operates at a collection level. A rolling upgrade is indeed the usual approach, but rolling upgrades and shapshots don't answer the original question of how to load a 2.4 `mongodump` with v1 user schema into a 2.6 server that wants v2 schema ;-).