# how can I load a mongodump of v2.4 database

Tags: mongodb

I have been given a mongodump of a system that is still running mongodb v2.4, and I want to load it into a system that is running v3.4.  I am having a number of problems with this:

- Firstly, It looks like the process to properly load the data is to do
  a rolling restore [mongorestore issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181769/mongorestore-issue-cannot-restore-users-with-schema-version-1-to-a-system-with#25273748#25273748).
- Secondly, I cannot find a version of MongoDB prior to version 3.0 on the [MongoDB download center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous).

Note: I am running Mac for development and Centos 7 for production.

It appears to me that I am stuck.  Help Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mac all MongoDB binaries you can download from below link

```
https://www.mongodb.org/dl/osx?_ga=2.218637342.62467748.1534239415-735789874.1531276044
```

For CentOS 7(RHEL Linux 64-bit*64) all MongoDB binaries you can download from below link

```
https://www.mongodb.org/dl/linux/x86_64-rhel70?_ga=2.147743408.62467748.1534239415-735789874.1531276044
```